# Generate Simple Mate In 1 From Tablebases (for kids)

Tags: engines, database, problems, tablebases

I was trying to find a kid's app for chess that has some incredibly simple problems. However, all the apps I found had rather tricky problems. So I thought I would download 3 piece table bases and use SCID (or grep, if necessary) to create a 3-piece Mate-In-One tablebase PGN. Then just use that in iChess or any other problem app that allows PGN imports.

Much to my chagrin, the tablebases aren't in PGN format as I expected (and I cant even read them in a text editor. Guess I really misunderstand how these tablebases work).

Any solutions out there?

Comment: Tablebases have their own format which aren't human readable. But, would you really need a tablebase for this? Isn't that a bit overkill?

Comment: Just the most direct solution I (thought that) I came up with. How would you go about it (my idea also expanded to 4,5 and 6 piece endgames as appropriate).

Comment: Well, think of a position that is checkmate say with K+R v K, and then move the rook somewhere else. You can probably think of new positions faster than they solve them.

Comment: Can't you take any database of real games and search for games that end in mate and then extract the position one move before the last?

Comment: @user1583209 That would be a better approach. FICS and Lichess has many such games. But we are here to answer the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible to generate mates in 1,2,3 etc with tablebase, but that's probably not what you want. You should understand:

- You will need good programming knowledge
- You will need a week generating 6-men tablebase mates
- You will generate too many mates than you can possibly study

If you are confident in programming, you can do this:

- Modify the Gaviota tablebase generator (ask the author for source code). Find where it calculates distance-to-mate, if it's one (or two or three), print the position out.
- Modify the Syzygy tablebase generator. Syzygy reports distance-to-zero, so you may need to use online probing (e.g. Nalimov) or an engine.
- Use the public API in https://syzygy-tables.info. Start from a randomised position. Use the API result to move your position to mate-in-one.

If you don't have any idea what I'm talking about, generating mate positions with tableabse is not for you. You should:

- Buy a book with mate-in-one positions. There is an Android app that can read a chess diagram and convert it to PGN.

**EDIT**: You shouldn't generate total random FENs. You should try to generate FENs that either side has an extra rook, queen etc.

Comment: The API looks like the trick. Any pointers on generating random FENs?

Comment: https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Generate_random_chess_position is a start

Comment: @Kale Yeah, that should work although not very efficient. You should not generate total random FENs. Your FEN will be most likely result in a mate if either side has extra material.

Comment: @Kale If you think my answer is sufficient for you to get started, please put a tick and accept it!

Comment: Yes, more specifically, I meant random within the limit of X number of pieces.